# Divide matrix up into smaller matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I have a matrix A size ixi, and i want to divide it into smaller matrices such that each sub matrix fits the dimensions of matrix B size jxj. How do I do this?

```
B = mat2cell(A,size(B));
```

doesn't seem to do it.

note: the number of sub matrices = sqrt(n)  i.e. if A is 100x100 then there will be 10 sub matrices, If A is 81x81 there will be 9 sub matrices.

Thanks

Comment: yes, it is being created by squaring a matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `mat2cell`, if you want to split a matrix into two, you have to give the size for each groups of rows/columns. So if you need to divide a 2-by-2 array into four 1-by-1 arrays, it's `mat2cell(array,[1 1],[1 1])`.

```
nSub = sqrt(size(A,1));

B = mat2cell(A,nSub*ones(1,nSub),nSub*ones(1,nSub));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try repmat. That'll reorganise your axb data into smaller matrices of pxqxr as you require.